# ansible playbook local_action to calculate value and assign to variable

Tags: ansible

i am new to ansible world. below is my ansible playbook and in that before applying template value for tomcat port. i am tryiny to calculate the port based on exiting no of tomcat instance on the remote server.

how can get the value as an variable using local_action after running an shell?

---

```
- 
  hosts: "{{Server}}"
  tasks:
    - 
      ignore_errors: true
      name: "find no of Tomcat Instance available on the Server"
      register: Tomcat_Instance_no
      shell: "find /example -name tomcat-users.xml -type f -print | wc -l"

    - debug: var=Tomcat_Instance_no
    #- local_action: copy content="{{ Tomcat_Instance_no.stdout }}" dest="/tmp/{{Server}}_Tomcat_Instance_no"
    #- local_action: "shell sh define-tomcat-instance-port.sh {{Server}} {{IName}} {{ Tomcat_Instance_no.stdout }}"
    ****- local_action: "shell sh http_port=$(( {{ Tomcat_Instance_no.stdout }} * 100 + 8080))"
      register: HTPN
    - local_action: "shell sh shutdown_port=$(( {{ Tomcat_Instance_no.stdout }} * 100 + 8005))"
      register: SHPN
    - local_action: "shell sh https_port=$(( {{ Tomcat_Instance_no.stdout }} * 100 + 8043))"
      register: SSPN
    - local_action: "shell sh ajp_port=$(( {{ Tomcat_Instance_no.stdout }} * 100 + 8009))"
      register: AJPN**

    #-
      #name: bare include
      #include_vars: "{{Server}}_{{IName}}.json"

    - 
      ignore_errors: true
      name: "find no of Tomcat Instance available on the Server"
      copy:
        src: "{{ WORKSPACE }}/instance/"
        dest: /example/{{IName}}
        group: "{{IGID}}"
        owner: "{{IUID}}"
        mode: 0755
    - 
      name: Deliver configuration files for tomcat
      template: src={{ item.src }} dest={{ item.dest }} backup=yes
      with_items:
          - { src: 'server.xml.j2', dest: '/example/{{IName}}/conf/server.xml' }
          - { src: 'set_env.sh.j2', dest: '/example/{{IName}}/scripts/set_env.sh' }
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You need [set_fact](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/set_fact_module.html):

```
- set_fact:
    HTPN: "{{ tomcat_no | int * 100 + 8080 }}"
    SHPN: "{{ tomcat_no | int * 100 + 8005 }}"
    SSPN: "{{ tomcat_no | int * 100 + 8043 }}"
    AJPN: "{{ tomcat_no | int * 100 + 8009 }}"
  vars:
    tomcat_no: "{{ Tomcat_Instance_no.stdout }}"
```

I also defined `tomcat_no` alias to use in `set_fact` task to reduce typing.